# How to select last page in "Print When Expression" in iReport?

Tags: ireport

I want to print some specific details only on last page in iReport using `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}` and `$V{PAGE_COUNT}`  variables. I don't want to use "Last page footer" or similar because it doesn't fit in my desired position.
When I type `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($V{PAGE_COUNT})`  condition in "Print When Expression", nothing happens. Any suggestions?
Also, is there any place where I can see the description of variables and other features in iReport?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you consider using band `Summary`?

Comment: @lschin <code> Summary </code> is positioned underneath the <code> Page Footer </code>. I want it to be above the <code> Page Footer </code>.

Comment: and I don't know why SO doesn't parse my formatting tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Creating new group above all groups will solve the problem. In that group footer you enter things you want to see only on last page

Answer (score 0):

create a new group give it a name and then you can use print when expression